# How can I disable one button of a jQuery-UI buttonset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button, jqueryi-ui-buttonset

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/UVHtu/19/

I need to fill in the blank:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="options">
    <input type="radio" id="op_a" name="op" value="a" />
    <label for="op_a">Option A</label>
    <input type="radio" id="op_b" name="op" value="b" />
    <label for="op_b">Option B</label>
    <input type="radio" id="op_c" name="op" value="c" />
    <label for="op_c">Option C</label>
</div>
<input type="button" id="disable_button" value="Disable Option B" />
​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#options").buttonset();

$("#disable_button").click(function(){
    // What goes here to disable option B?
});
```

​

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("#options").buttonset();

$("#disable_button").click(function(){
    // What goes here?
    $('#op_b').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#options").buttonset("refresh");
});
```

Comment: Excellent concise answer, thought I will use a jQuery selector in place of `document.getElementById()` and `attr("disabled", "disabled")` in place of `disabled = true`

Comment: In that case I would suggest using `prop` instead of `attr`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: Good point. I'm not 100% the version of jQuery this site uses supports prop() yet. But I do need to get in the habit....